# how to change directory?

Tags: directory, mail

I've downloaded your-freedom in Home /local/Freedom

I need steps of how to go there in terminal as to launch the software please!

am a beginner in Ubuntu so could you please HELP ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the cd (change directory)command

```
cd ~/local/Freedom
```

use ls to list your current directory, pwd to show your current directory

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

ls - list contents of a directory

sudo - "super-user do" (grants administrator rights)

cd - change directory

aptitude - APT package management system (update, install, remove, search)

clear - clear screen

chmod - change file access permissions

chown - change file and group ownership

cp - copy

mv - move

rm - remove

cat - concatenate files (dump to screen)

nano - basic text editor

vi - advanced text editor

fdisk - partition table manipulator

df - disk free (remaining / used disk space)

users - users currently logged in

useradd - add a user

usermod - modify existing user

uname - show system data (try uname -a)

mount - mount a file system, cd or removable drive

umount - un-mount a file system, cd or removable drive

top - show current running processes

touch - create new, empty, file

reboot - reboot your system

shutdown - shutdown your system

passwd - change user password

ping - ping a network device or location (ping google.com)

more - show output one screen at a time

exit - logout of the terminal

eject - eject a cdrom or removable device