# How can I change download location in aria2?

Tags: download-manager

I am really new to ubuntu and using 14.04 version. I have heard that Aria2 is one of the best download managers. How can I change the directory using terminal so that it can put the file on a specific hard drive after it finishes downloading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139598/how-to-change-directory)

Comment: @the_Seppi this question is not a duplicate at all. That is a global question this is application specific.

Answer (score 9):

-d, --dir=

```
The directory to store the downloaded file.
```

This option is per download basis, you have to do this every time.

Alternatively, you can install uGet, http://uGetdm.com , which is a front-end to aria2. You can also ask for help on the uGet Forum, http://uGetdm.com/forum

Comment: I have tried using that command before and after a copied torrent link. But unfortunately I failed. If its not too much can you please show me a step by step process?

Comment: A full command for a magnet link would be:
```aria2c -d /path/to/download/dir 'magnet:...' ```